# DB2 how to find two users who are active in the same date

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

I'm trying two find users who were active in the same date, I have code that runs

```
select place,date,user, artNumber

from jobs
where user in (

select user2

from userActive

where date between 20180101 and 20181011 and user2 = 'nightJob')
```

This just give me when nightJob have been active, how can I match so the result return which other user have been active in the same time as nightJob, I would love an explanation of the solution because I'm trying to learn.

I sound like amateur and maybe I am, but can someone explain my code, I've written it, but I just want to check if I understand it correctly. I don't want fixed results, its over hundred users but nightJob is always that specific username.

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJsUU.jpg)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  hi Gordon, thx for your post, I´ve upload a picture that clarifies my disered result.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
select place,date,user, artNumber
from jobs
where user in (
select user2
from userActive where jobs.user=userActive.user2 and
date between 20180101 and 20181011 and user2 = 'nightJob')
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution will add two more fields to the output, and I will let you complete the SQL command.  I work in Oracle, not DB2, but, I think I can help.
First, assuming your date field defines date values to the second, you need to use a function to modify the date: to_char(date, 'YYYYMMDD').
Also, you want two (or more) users who worked at the same time, so, I am including the second user in the output.  Also, my results will show that the dates from the two tables are matched.  My query may return duplicates.  Check the results and modify the query, as needed.

```
Select jobs.place, to_char(jobs.date, 'YYYYMMDD'), jobs.user, jobs.artNumber,
    UserActive.user2, to_char(UserActive.date, 'YYYYMMDD')
    from jobs
    join UserActive
      on (to_char(jobs.date, 'YYYYMMDD'), to_char(UserActive.date, 'YYYYMMDD')
   where jobs.user <> UserActive.user2
     and /* put more filters here, if desired */
;
```

Comment: Thanks dude,  I’m getting a error message that says ”vaild tokens (.,” I dont understamd why I’m getting that message, do you have an ide?